# sqlite database not migrated to postgresql when pushed to heroku server (django)

Tags: django, heroku, dbmigrate

I pushed my app to heroku, but it seems that the database did not migrate (the database has 0 tables and 0 entries). How can I migrate it correctly?

Comment: i'm not too familiar with heroku, but was your sqlite db underversion control? How did you transfer your dev db to heroku?  You could `dumpdata` locally and `loaddata` on your heroku

Comment: The db was under version control, but this is actually the first version as I was migrating a new app from an old computer. I'm going to try to dumpdata locally and then transfer it to the new database server.

Comment: are you using migrate in copying your data to Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Starter-tier databases, there is a delay in populating those stats. You can see if there are tables immediately if you `psql` in:

```
$ heroku pg:psql -a app_name
psql=> \dt
[...tables...]
```

Also, please see my answer here on using postgres locally instead of sqlite3 (recommended):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373024/95741

Comment: Thanks, I ran that command and it gave "No relations found". I am indeed using the starter-tier database so maybe I'll wait until tomorrow and check it again. In the meantime, I think I'll take that advice and migrate my local database to postresql, then push it again to heroku.

Comment: the `\dt` command is immediate. If it finds nothing, there's nothing there. Migrate to postgres locally and try again. import/export guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export