# Migrate Data and schema from development to production rails heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have facing problems with migrating data to my heroku app which has Postgresql as database for my hosted site(Production). At my development site i have rails 3.2.13 with Sqlite3 as database. I have followed [Ruby on rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning)

i have used `git push heroku` to update my site at heroku. i also want to update database along with data. But `heroku run rake db:migrate` migrates schema not data. I tried `db:push` to push data to heroku but i get error

`dependency.rb in 'to_specs' :Could not find sequel (~) 3.20.0`

also i have searched and found that i should first my sqlite data to dump.sql and then run

`heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR --app app_name < file.sql` as answered in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371394/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371394/rails-populate-heroku-database-with-development-sqlite3-data)
but it failed with 
`the local psql command could not be located`

please tell me what i am doing wrong. or what is the right way to update heroku postgresql with my development sqlite3 data.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to install psql (the Postgres client command line tool) for that linked answer to work. Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: i am on windows. let me download the Postgres tool and check.

Comment: i've got the same error after installing tool for postgresql :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to fill the production database with the data that you have now in the developement database. Because, if you have problems with your production database in the future, and you need to refill it again, your development db may changed (e.g dropped), and you are not going to be able to do it again.

For this need, Rails provides seeds in `db/seeds.rb` file. You should create all the neccessary objects there.

Then when you push your code to Heroku, Heroku is going to prepare the database, create the schema, and seed it. If you need to seed the db manually, you can run `bundle exec rake db:seed`, if you want to run it in Heroku: `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`